# Regular expression which accepts 'whitespace' character as well

Tags: regex, whitespace

This is my regular expression. But it does not accept white space. How to modify it so that it will accept white space in the middle or end but should not accept only white spaces.

```
    /^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/'
```

Comment: Do you need to allow for whitespace at the start of the match? I can update my answer if you do.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you. It will allow whitespace after the first character.
`^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s._-]+$`

Comment: @Roney Michael, you should comment on other peoples post, not edit them if they contain errors (apart from typos, formatting, etc.)

Comment: @Anthon: My mistake; won't happen again. :)

Comment: In regards to the edit: `([a-zA-Z0-9._-]|\s)` could be better expressed as `([a-zA-Z0-9._-\s])`.

Comment: @RoneyMichael No problem, someone 'OK-ed' your edit, and that person should have caught it.

Comment: @Anthon I OK-ed the edit myself. I was making the exact same change myself when I got the notification. For some reason my tool was telling me it wasn't valid regex when I first tried it.

Comment: @Dracs: I could not see who did that, I thought was one of the other reviewers making a mistake. Please roll back my change or correct the answer. Sorry for the extra work I wanted to make sure Roney knew the correct procedure of commenting in these kind of cases.

Answer (score 0):

ya i got the solution.I modified the regex in the following way and this is working fine. Anyway thanks :)

```
    /^[a-zA-Z]+[a-z A-Z0-9._-]+$/'
```

Comment: If @Dracs' answer helped you out, please accept it. This post would be better off as a comment beneath it.